# how to delete a document from firebase in firestore by using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first react project by using firebase, everything is correct which all upload function works very well, also all images can be shown, but i use `firebase.firestore.collection('image').document(doc.id).delete()`  when i want to delete one of the images, it shows an error which is:

> Uncaught TypeError: db.document is not a function

I do not know what is going on, can someone help to resolve it, please?

`projectFirestore = firebase.firestore()` in the firebase config file.

```
import React from 'react';
import useFirestore from '../hooks/useFirestore';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config';
const ImageGrid = ({ setSelectedImg }) => {
  const { docs } = useFirestore('images');
  const db = projectFirestore.collection('image');
  return (
    <div className="img-grid">
      {docs &&
        docs.map(doc => (
          <motion.div
            className="img-wrap"
            key={doc.id}
            layout
            whileHover={{ opacity: 1 }}
            onClick={() => setSelectedImg(doc.url)}
          >
            <motion.img
              src={doc.url}
              alt="uploaded pic"
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{ delay: 1 }}
            />
            <button className='showBt' onClick={() => db.document(doc.id).delete()}>-</button>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ImageGrid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc), not `document()`.

Comment: thanks man, it works, i used document() from youtube which he uses this method, anyway i should look at the official document first.

Comment: That tutorial might be for a language other than JavaScript.  The SDKs are not all exactly the same between each language.